# starting a sentence with to+infinitive

Tags: infinitives

I want to write a question to mean that **if a company wants to become customer-oriented, its culture must change and commitment to customer orientation must first be created in the higher top level of the organization.** I want to rephrase this to start the sentence with to+infinitive as it seems more beautiful. My sentence follows:

> To become customer-oriented, the organization’s culture must change and commitment to customer-orientation must first be created in higher levels of the organization.

Is the sentence above correct? Can anyone explain a little bit when a sentence can start with to+infinitive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To become customer-oriented, the organization’s culture must change and commitment to customer-orientation must first be created in higher levels of the organization.

One can start a sentence with an *infinitive phrase* like "to become customer-oriented", but I see one problem with your sentence: the phrase modifies two clauses at once. One clause is

> the organization’s culture must change

which gives

> The organization’s culture must change *to become customer-oriented*.

which is okay, although it diverges from your original sentence: there, it was *the company* that was to become *customer-oriented*, now it's the *culture*.

But the other clause is

> commitment to customer-orientation must first be created in higher levels of the organization

which gives

> Commitment to customer-orientation must first be created in higher levels of the organization *to become customer-oriented*.

which is strange: it's as if we wanted the *commitment* to become *customer-oriented*.

You might remodel a bit:

> .. and in its (i.e., the organization's) higher levels a commitment to customer-orientation must...

But the resulting sentence still might be bulky.

As an aside, I'd recommend the site called lang-8.com for proofreading purposes.

Answer (score 1):

According to Michael Swan in his classic Practical English Usage you shouldn't start a sentence with infinitive except for the verbs *To hear* and *To see*, otherwise it is old English and should be reserved for instructions only. You should reword it to **In order to become** or **So as to become**, though both are quite formal sentences, I am afraid to say.

Comment: The proposed sentence *is* an instruction.

Comment: I mean a instruction as in a manual. This is much more of a suggestion/piece of advice rather than an instruction.