# Verb+ing and to+Verb as subjects

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

> 1)**Playing basketball for UConn** is her favorite fantasy.
>
> 2)**To play basketball for UConn** is her favorite fantasy.

Are both sentences correct? If yes, what is the difference in meaning between them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [starting a sentence with to+infinitive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40539/starting-a-sentence-with-toinfinitive)

Comment: 'To' at the beginning before a verb has the same meaning as elsewhere, marking an infinitive clause. It is quite correct to start a sentence with 'To play' But it is uncommon. We usually use the ing-form at the beginning, or use dummy subject 'it' and move the infinitive clause away from the beginning: *It is her favourite fantasy to play basketball for UConn.*

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul  ThankYou for your reply. But what is the difference in meaning if the sentence is started with a gerund and when the sentence is started with Infinitive?

Comment: I think there's no difference in meaning.